Exploring Quantum Attacks in Q1 Model on Symmetric Primitives with Better than Quadratic Speedup
I'm exploring quantum attacks (in the Q1 model) on symmetric structures, including hash functions, block ciphers, modes of operation and stream ciphers with time complexity beyond quadratic speedup.
I've found a couple of resources:

Quantum cryptanalysis of the full AES-256-based Davies–Meyer, Hirose and MJH hash functions (Springer),
Security of Hash Functions against Attacks Using Quantum Computers (webpage of NTT and
Beyond Quadratic Speedups in Quantum Attacks on Symmetric Schemes (Springer).

I’d appreciate any additional recommendations you might have.

ou might want to include the URLs that correspond to Link1, link2 and Link3

Hi Ali and welcome. Cross posted from Quantum Computing on request. If you are cross posting at the very minimum include a link. Personally I don't like cross posting as answers on one site will not be visible on the other. So generally I'd wait for an answer and possibly delete before migrating the question. Finally a hint: when copying a post simply hit edit on the source post and then copy the markdown instead of copying the rendered post.

I've also edited the post to include the title of the referenced papers. Please always reference source material, not just by linking as links may become out of date.
